# term for trees that make the soil inhospitable so that nothing can grow there after they are removed

Tags: terminology

There's a technical term that I cannot remember, which is applied to trees that change the soil composition where they've grown, so that even after they've been removed, nothing will grow there. Would someone please refresh my memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly you are thinking of [allelopathy](https://garden.lovetoknow.com/wiki/Tree_Roots_Effects_on_Soil), which is a general term for plants poisoning the soil around them.

[Juglone](https://www.extension.iastate.edu/news/2005/jul/070701.htm), associated with trees in the walnut family, is an example of an allelopathic effect on the soil.

Comment: If you do have a walnut and you want to grow _something_ underneath it, raspberries tend to do well under walnut trees, even black walnuts.